# Is there is any component or pod that makes the same scrolling tabs in the video?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, cocoapods, uicontrol

[image]

Is there is any component or pod that makes the same or near scrolling tabs in the video?

I've searched a lot but all I find was for the tabbar.

You're grateful if you suggest keywords that I can search with them.

Comment: Why dont you try with UISegmentedControl. Works like a charm and its totally iOS like, this video you provided looks like Android...

Answer (score 1):

This question will likely be closed for "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more" ... however...

There are various ways to approach this. One would be:

- create a custom view
- use a bezier path on a `CAShapeLayer` to create the "appearance"
- add a scroll view as a subview
- put buttons in a horizontal stack view in the scroll view

When a button is tapped, scroll it to the center and take whatever other actions you desire (such as changing the information displayed in the center).

Pretty straightforward --- you just need to start working on it.